# Apple ID linked to another account

Tags: iphone, apple-id

Me and my ex shared an Apple ID, we broke up in 2015 and she moved as well, and therefore I had to change her Apple ID login from the shared ID to another email address.

I have now battled for over a year with trying to update my iPhone with new info. Due to previous iPhone and iPad theft. I could not login into iCloud, so I could not report the device as stolen.

I have lost all my music and photos and my only request is to be assisted to get the info from the iCloud up till the time that the Apple ID was changed I think in October 2015, please assist me

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what help you're looking for?  Do you want to access the old Apple ID so you get your music and photos downloaded?  Or are you trying to setup a new Apple ID with your new device?

Comment: yes as I have lost 19 years of photos and music

Comment: the id has changed as said, but they will pick up that these phones were linked for a long time

Comment: The photos and music are tied to a specific Apple ID.  If you no longer have access to that ID you probably lost access to those, as well.  That's one of the reasons Apple says not to share IDs.  Did your ex change the password of the shared ID (that had all the photos and music)?